# Take control of a Windows application with VBA (DDE /OLE/ODBC/ADO)

Tags: vba, controls, ole, dde

Good morning all.
This is a subject that I have been trying to dig for a long time but which is only very little documented on the web: How to control a third-party application via VBA?

The objective is to create a link (bridge) of an Office tool (Excel / Access) in order to carry out manipulation on a Windows application, for example pasting the clipboard in paint or in notepad. For efficiency's, I don't want to use the sendkeys command which we can't trust.

To my knowledge there is a DDE method which would allow it but it seems to be obsolete. Can you confirm ?

Here is a code using DDE in order to connect to Word and send it the Print command
...

```
 channelNumber = Application.DDEInitiate( _
    app:="WinWord", _
    topic:="C:\FORMLETR.DOC")
Application.DDEExecute channelNumber, "[FILEPRINT]"
Application.DDETerminate channelNumber
```

...

Trying to modify it to paste our clipboard on paint, here is the code that does not work:
...

```
channelNumber = Application.DDEInitiate( _
    app:="mspaint", _
    topic:="C:\Test.png")
Application.DDEExecute channelNumber, "[PASTE]"
Application.DDETerminate channelNumber
...
```

Result:
I have an error "Run time error '13': Type missmatch" in the first line although the file opens.

Let's try with the notepad:

...

```
Sub DDEtoBlocNotes()
Dim Datarange As Range
chan = Application.DDEInitiate(app:="NOTEPAD", topic:="C:\Users\User1\Documents\Access\Test.txt")
Set Datarange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
Datarange.Copy
Application.DDEExecute chan, "[EDITIONCOLLER]"
Application.DDETerminate chan
End Sub
```

...

Result: same error as before despite opening the document.
"Run time error '13': Type missmatch"

Can you help me solve this problem please?
Do you have documentation on the attributes of DDE commands?
Do you know of another way to connect to a third-party application to send commands to it? (OLE / ODBC / ADO)?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: [This SO question about controlling windows apps with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374592/using-vba-to-control-another-program-entirely_) might be useful. I'm not very knowledgable on the topic but you might find looking into [Windows API calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-api-list)  handy too if you want to manipulate the window itself.

Comment: Don't use DDE. Forget all about it. Some apps may support it for backwards compatibility, but it is like Sanskrit. The traditional way to interact with other applications using VBA is through COM. It is *way* too broad a subject to quicky explain, but basically it allows you to create an instance of application that you can then control via it's COM-interface, i.e. the properties and methods that it has available through its interface. COM has been superseeded by .Net (almost 20 years ago), but there are still countless applications relying on it (even Office itself).

Comment: On a more practical level, you cannot 'control' just any 3rd-party application. (Yes, you can tap into the Windows API. You probably do not want to). Notepad for instance doesn't have a COM interface. Sure, you can launch it using VBA, but that's about it. And why would you want to? But you can control virtually anything in say Word or Excel via VBA. `Dim xl: Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` will give you virtually full control over Excel using code.

Comment: The lesson to take from this is that in VBA, the preferred way of controlling another application is to tap into its COM interface, if has any. Note that .Net applications have to explicitly implement COM-interop.

Comment: Arno van Boven :"The traditional way to interact with other applications using VBA is through COM. " Thanks for guiding me through this topic. Could you share any example on how to proceed to connect to a COM with another software ? Any documentation to share ? Any code ?
Many thanks

Comment: Well, for your requirement (talk to Paint from VBA), you are out of luck. MSPaint does not implement a COM-interface (neither does Notepad, btw), which means that you cannot talk to it through VBA directly. You'll have to revert to clunky SendKeys or try dabble with low-level WinAPI calls. However it is probably better to narrow down your objective. There is no catch-all solution for what you say in your OP.

Comment: Arno van Boven, Understood. Anyway, notepad or paint was just an example to expose my needs, cause the software I want to control is a software we use at my office. please  kindly provide me with documentation with "How to interract with COM in VBA.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-automation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374592/using-vba-to-control-another-program-entirely

Comment: The most important question IMHO is: does the application at your office actually support automation?