# Office Analysis Prompts Value Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code to open prompts window in excel:

Application.Run("SAPExecuteCommand", "ShowPrompts")

But my problem is I dont know how to put value in Prompts window through Macro. Can anyone help about that? Any code sample?

For instance in this picture I want to put 1000 in 0BUCHUNG field. I would like to do this through Macro code and click ok. I cant record a Macro while doing these steps I dont know why, that is why I am asking maybe there is kind of code to perform it in Macro. [Prompts Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ELRk.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using VBA to control another program entirely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374592/using-vba-to-control-another-program-entirely)

Comment: @jsheeran unfortunately this is not I look for.